# Cost function from a weighted CES production function

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, optimization, cost-functions, ces-function

I want to find the cost function  given the CES production function:
$$
Y = F(x_1,x_2) = (\lambda x_1^ \rho+(1-\lambda)x_2^\rho)^\frac{1}{\rho}
$$
with $0<\rho<1$.
So far I have set up the Lagrangian and I have relative prices equal to MRS
$$
\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{\lambda x_1^{\rho-1}}{(1-\lambda)x_2^{\rho-1}}
$$

and tried to rearrange it, but I only get to:

$$
(p_1^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}}+p_2^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}})^{\frac{1}{\rho}}(1-\lambda)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}}x_2^\rho= p_2^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}}(\lambda^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}}x_1^\rho+(1-\lambda)^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}}x_2^\rho)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}
$$

I tried this since without the weights you get $Y$ on the right hand side and can then continue to solve for conditional demand $\hat{x}(p1,p2,Y)$ but I don't know what to do with the weights $\lambda$ and $(1-\lambda)$

Do you know what I can do here.